# If you resize a pink noise image, will the pink noise be preserved?

Tags: matlab, random, noise

I have a pink noise image of e.g. 500x500 resolution. If I resize the image to a new size with imresize, will the resulting image be pink-noise or will it be something close to it, but not the same?

What I thought is that with imresize, you change the image in a non-random way, so the result will not still be exactly pink-noise.

Comment: the answer is nearly yes, because of the Shannon theorem and of the effect on the spectrum of an ideal filtering  followed by downsampling. sorry, you'll have to learn many things on the (discrete) Fourier transform/series before understanding those ($imresize$ is **not** an ideal filter, that's why it's only nearly yes, modulo the aliasing produced by the non-perfect filter)